# django rest framework: limit fields that can be updated

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want users to be able to update only one specific field. For example:

**models.py**

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

**views.py**

```
class SnippetList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer


class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

Once the `Snippet` is created, the user should only be able to update `title` field.

I know I can achieve that by something like this:

**serializers.py**

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

In serializer class. But I want to know, is there a way that browsable API show only `title` field in edit form? And also skip validation for fields that are not required?

Comment: Did you find any solution for the same?

Answer (score 13):

Django REST Framework provides the `read_only` and `write_only` attributes for controlling what is used for editing and what is not.

## serializers.py

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'code': {'read_only': True},
            'lineos': {'read_only': True},
            'language': {'read_only': True},
            'style': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

The above will return all the fields on read requests but only title will be writable.
You can find more at the official documentation:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

Comment: thanks! half way there... the `read_only` fields are gone. but they are gone in `POST` and `PUT` forms :(.

Comment: This way you will not be able `create` the `read_only` fields. I guess the OP wants to create the fields, but not update.

Answer (score 0):

While @petkostas answer is correct, it doesn't give you a full picture of how to achieve it.

First, Create a new serializer; let's call it `SnippetUpdateSerializer`

Now, you may have custom serializer fields like `serializers.MethodFieldSerializer` that you would have defined in `SnipperSerializer`; which you may not want to write again in your new serializer. A good approach is to use **inheritance**.

Taking the example from the question

```py
class SnippetUpdateSerializer(SnippetSerializer): #<- pay attention here 

    class Meta(SnippetSerializer.Meta): # <- pay attention here 
    
        SnippetSerializer.Meta.extra_kwargs.update({ # update the dictionary
            'id': {'read_only': True},
            'code': {'read_only': True}, # you can also use {write_only: True} if you want this to be write only
            'lineos': {'read_only': True},
            'language': {'read_only': True},
            'style': {'read_only': True}
        }) # you may completely override  by just using extra_kwargs, instead of SnippetSerializer.Meta.extra_kwargs
```

Now in your `SnippetUpdateView`, use the above serializer.

If you are using class based views then set `serializer_class = SnippetUpdateSerializer`

Another approach is to return `bad request`, from your update view if the user requests contain read_only fields. (not recommended)

Comment: Regards the HTTP error status code, I'd say it should be 403(Forbidden), not 400(Bad Request) because as per the reference
"The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: @Montaro, I believe that 400 is still the right way since once you make a field `read_only` that field can't be used or is malformed and will be ignored as said in [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only), and hence 400 is appropriate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 .